Using a fine-tuned model for the pipeline method in Hugging Face's Transformers
I'm trying to replicate the Long-Form Transcription technique in the README for Whisper. The method loads a pre-existing model via using the pipeline method.
import torch
from transformers import pipeline

device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
pipe = pipeline(
  "automatic-speech-recognition",
  model="openai/whisper-large-v2",
  chunk_length_s=30,
  device=device,
)

I have a fine-tuned version of whisper-large-v3. The version is saved as a local file whisper_v3_finetuned.pt. How do I load this fine-tuned version into the pipeline?
I tried to just replace the model line but it didn't work. I went through the documentation on Hugging Face and I couldn't easily find an explanation of how to load a local file of a model.

Have you tried to insert the path of the folder with the model? What error do you get?
